# Creating postgresql database in Docker with Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, docker

I would like to create postgresql database in docker with my Django project. I'm trying to do it using `init.sql` file but it doesn't work:

`settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'aso',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

`init.sql`:

```
CREATE USER postgres;
CREATE DATABASE aso;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE aso TO postgres;
```

My updated `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
FROM library/postgres
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-07-05 14:02:41 UTC
web_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 145: exec: python3: not found
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
dockerpri_web_1 exited with code 127
```

I was trying with this `Dockerfile`, too:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
FROM library/postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER docker
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD docker
ENV POSTGRES_DB aso
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 PROJECT/backend/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: The [official docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) seem to point to a different Dockerfile. Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: I am not sure you meant what I have added to post?

Comment: I think maybe you are confused how the `Dockerfile` works with regards to multiple `FROM` instructions. Can you also post your `docker-compose.yml`? What you are currently doing isn't possible but I can offer a suggestion.

Comment: I will be grateful. I have updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `Dockerfile` example isn't valid. It should just have one `FROM` instruction. Remove the PostgreSQL stuff so it is just:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Next, I am going to answer the question of how to create a PostgreSQL user and database since that is what your `init.sql` is doing.

According to the `postgres` image documentation at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/, there are `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` environment variables available to us. The `POSTGRES_USER` variable will create a user and database with privileges to that user. An example amend to your `docker-compose.yml` would be:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: aso
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 PROJECT/backend/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

On start, this will initialize the PostgreSQL database with a username of `aso`, a database of `aso`, and a password of `somepass`. Then, you can just amend your `settings.py` to use this username, database, and password.

I'll also add, that if you wanted to run other arbitrary SQL or scripts during database startup, you can do so by adding `sql` or `sh` files to the `postgres` image at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Read more about this at https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image.

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect answer, everything works properly.